# pd.read_csv() incorrectly truncating timestamps formatted as scientific notation in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, timestamp

I have a dataset in csv format that automatically downloads from a webservice.  The csv file has the following general format:

```
csv file in excel
[Timestamp]  [Column B]
1.51258E+12  A
1.51242E+12  B
1.51242E+12  C
```

When the `['Timestamp']` formatting is changed in excel from 'General' to 'Number', the full number shows as follows:

```
csv file (formatting changed in excel)
[Timestamp]   [Column B]
1512584017891  A
1512423886571  B
1512423818970  C
```

I need to automate the processing of the csv file, and so I cannot go into the file in excel every time to switch the format from general to timestamp.  What I'm finding is that `pd.read_csv()` is importing the `['Timestamp']` csv column as scientific notation, leaving a truncated `df['Timestamp'] dtype=float64`.

```
df (in pandas)
[Timestamp]  [Column B]
1.512580e+12  A
1.512420e+12  B
1.512420e+12  C
```

Notice how now `df['Timestamp']` added a 0 prior to the E+12 when importing.  I tried to convert `df['Timestamp'].astype('int64')`, but this showed what I was worried about: pd.read_csv() substituted the hidden digits for zeros.

```
In[1]: df['Timestamp'].astype('int64').head(3)

Out[1]: 1512580000000
        1512420000000
        1512420000000
        Name: Timestamp, dtype: int64
```

Is there a way to 1) import the right timestamp, and then 2) convert that timestamp to the following format: 12/14/2017 10:32:12 AM?

Comment: If you open up the .csv file in a text editor, do you see the full precision time-stamp? If not then this is an excel issue.

Comment: Whats the result of `cat data.csv | head`? where `data.csv` is the name of your file...

Comment: FHTMitchell - Yes, the full timestamp displays there.

Comment: Well if I store your csv file and then do `pd.read_csv` on it I get the full precision `np.int64`s in pandas. Can you post your code? (python 3.6, pandas 0.19.2).

Comment: So I converted the excel column to number and then back to general (showing scientific notation)...and the full timestamp then transfers to python.  Only issue is, this still requires some manual input.  I guess my revised question should be "How can I script python to change format of a csv file while it's still in excel?"  Not sure if this is possible even...

Comment: I don't use pandas, so I do not know how to fix your problem from within pandas (though there might be a way). However, if you are willing to drop down to a lower level (just Python and its standard library) you can definitely read the file with no data loss and convert the timestamps to a friendlier format. (If your timestamps are milliseconds from the Unix epoch, then check out the various facilities in the `time` module, just remember to divide by 1000 to get seconds.)

Comment: Where is this data ultimately supposed to wind up? What I mean is: Are you trying to build a CSV that a person is going to look at with Microsoft Excel? Are you going to show the nicely formatted date on the screen? For all practical purposes, there's no way to "lose data" if you are just reading the text. You can lose data when you try to coerce textual data into numeric data.

Comment: @JohnY Thanks for the help.  For this purpose, I'm trying to have a csv end up as a pandas.DataFrame. I will modify it using the pandas package, and then output to a csv.  The issue I might have had with the `open` is that the script I used only outputs as a print readout.  I still see scientific notation on that read out, but if I can convert that to a pd.DataFrame I may be able to adjust it to an int64 format (and see all figures).

Answer (score 0):

You can dictate the data type of each column with `pd.read_csv` with the optional `dtype` parameter. This should avoid the loss of data from starting with pandas' default interpretation and then converting after you've already read in the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('fname.csv', dtype = {'Timestamp': np.int64})
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt.  Unfortunately, the information loss still takes place.  Rather than it being a python issue, I think it's more of an excel issue.  I'm considering if converting to a txt file will help.

Comment: @ParalysisByAnalysis - I'm not sure what you mean by "converting to a txt file" (if it's a CSV, then it's already a text file), but you can absolutely just open the file as text from Python (using the built-in `open` function) and either parse it yourself, or use the `csv` module. (See my comment on your question above.)

Comment: @JohnY Thanks for that.  I attempted the `open` function combined with the `csv` module but unfortunately the same result occurred.

Comment: @ParalysisByAnalysis - That doesn't make any sense. I think you must have left out some information. But this answer is not the place to comment on it. I'll continue at your question.

Comment: @johny Excel has an issue where it only stores 15 digits of a number, so if you save as a .csv from excel it will round them - the issue is excel generating a bad .csv, not anything to do with how you read it. A workaround for this is to format the numbers as text when you're working with them in excel - then it won't round them when you save the .csv.

Comment: @JacobH - First of all, the data in question only has 13 digits, so it will fit without rounding. Second, the CSV is *not* generated by Excel; it comes from a Web service. The process that OP is trying to develop isn't meant to involve Excel at all. The whole point is to take the downloaded CSV and shove the data directly into pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
In the below answer, I have tried using pandas.to_datetime, to convert 
the epoch time into date time.
I'm reading data from csv like below:

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path) 
print(df) 

      Timestamp
0  1.512580e+12
1  1.512420e+12
2  1.512420e+12

df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='ms')
print(df)

            Timestamp
0 2017-12-06 17:06:40
1 2017-12-04 20:40:00
2 2017-12-04 20:40:00


df.applymap(type)


Timestamp
0   <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
1   <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
2   <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  That solves phase 2 of this problem.  However, I cannot use the `data=d` methodology since there are hundreds of rows and the csv itself is dynamic (constantly appended).  I appreciate your response to the second portion though!

Comment: no i dont have excel so i just made that dataframe from you and have made edit to the answer to read the data from csv

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to get pandas to read in your data properly. But I'm not knowledgeable enough with it to know how.

What I do know is that Python gives you the tools to take control of the reading and the critical parts of the data conversion yourself (so that you're not mercy to implicit and possibly lossy conversions performed by pandas).

In the comments, you said the raw, downloaded CSV contains all the timestamp digits when viewed in a text editor. So, let's say that raw data looks like this:

```
1512584017891,A
1512423886571,B
1512423818970,C
```

You can read the data with plain Python as follows:

```
with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip().split(','))
```

(If the raw CSV is larger or more complex or has the possibility of "troublesome" characters, such as commas that are part of the data and not merely delimiters, then you'll want to use the `csv` module instead of simply splitting on all commas.)

The above produces

```
['1512584017891', 'A']
['1512423886571', 'B']
['1512423818970', 'C']
```

So you see, you have all the digits. You can losslessly convert those digits to Python integers (which have arbitrary precision) with the built-in `int` function, or to Python floats (IEEE doubles) with the built-in `float` function. For example, if we start again from the raw CSV input:

```
with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.strip().split(',')
        ms = int(tokens[0])  # my guess is you have milliseconds
        label = tokens[1]
        print([ms, label])
```

That prints out

```
[1512584017891, 'A']
[1512423886571, 'B']
[1512423818970, 'C']
```

Do you see where I'm going with this? Maybe this is an appropriate place to pass the data along to pandas, maybe not. You can take it further with plain Python and hold off on giving control to pandas:

```
import time

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.strip().split(',')
        secs = int(tokens[0]) * 0.001
        label = tokens[1]
        print([time.ctime(secs), label])
```

The above produces

```
['Wed Dec  6 13:13:37 2017', 'A']
['Mon Dec  4 16:44:46 2017', 'B']
['Mon Dec  4 16:43:38 2017', 'C']
```

Note that the output of `time.ctime` is a formatted string, and that it truncates the fractions of a second. If you want a proper Python "timestamp" (which preserves down to microseconds, if available), better to use `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.strip().split(',')
        secs = int(tokens[0]) * 0.001
        label = tokens[1]
        print([datetime.fromtimestamp(secs), label])
```

which produces

```
[datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 6, 13, 13, 37, 891000), 'A']
[datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 4, 16, 44, 46, 571000), 'B']
[datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 4, 16, 43, 38, 970000), 'C']
```

Once you have a proper `datetime` object, you can do a number of things with it, including choosing a string formatted according to your own spec, or doing calculations with it. It also might be safe to pass `datetime` objects to pandas, I don't know.

The point is, wherever it is that pandas is failing you, you have the option of handling it yourself with just Python and its standard library.

Finally, since you said you want to ultimately wind up with another CSV as your output: I think it's worth mentioning that if *that* CSV is meant to be opened by a human being using Excel (or LibreOffice or whatever), then consider doing them a favor and output directly to a .xlsx file instead. And for that, you can once again use pandas, or "lower-level" packages like [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter). (This isn't very low-level, but it's lower-level than pandas. In fact, it's used *by* pandas, but you can use it directly for more control and richer functionality.)